# How to pass UIVIewController name as a parameter to particular function using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my scenario, I need to pass `UIVIewController` name and some more string values to particular `function`. I tried below code but not getting result.

**Passing Parameters To Particular Function**

```
self.accountoptionscall(vcName: UIViewController(), vcIdentifier: "profileviewcontroller", popUpVC: ProfileViewController.self)

func accountoptionscall<T: UIViewController>(vcName: UIViewController,vcIdentifier: String, popUpVC: T.self) {
            let viewcontrollers = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier) as! vcName
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontrollers)
        self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to pass vcName if you are passing the identifier. I don't see any use of vcName in this function. You can remove as! vcName and it will still work.

Comment: What result do you want to get? And what result are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I use it in my app, I think it can help you.

```swift
extension UIViewController {

  /// Load UIViewController type from UIStoryboard
  class func loadFromStoryboard<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
    let name = String(describing: T.self)
    let storybord = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil)
    if let viewController = storybord.instantiateInitialViewController() as? T {
      return viewController
    } else {
      fatalError("Error:  No initial view controller in \(name) storyboard!")
    }
  }
}
```

Here how you can use it:

```swift
  func loadVC<T: UIViewController>(controller: T) {
    let vc: T = T.loadFromStoryboard()
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    // or if use in appDelegate you can do it: window?.rootViewController = navigationVC
  }
```